# Appending Two-Dimensional Lists in Python

Tags: python

first post on here so take it easy on me.

I have been stuck on this program for my python class for a little while now and am not sure what I need to do to proceed.

I am getting errors on when I run my `create_commission()` function. I am pretty sure it is because I should not be using `count[]` but am not sure what I should be using. I am going off of my professors pseudocode which shows the following:

```
create_commission(s_list)
create c_list
for every person list in s_list
    create s_comm list
    s_comm[0] = person[0]
    s_comm[1] = person[1]
    s_comm[2] = find_commission(person[2])
    append s_comm to c_list
return c_list
```

I am not sure what I should be putting in the `person[]` spot.

Any and all help would be appreciated!

```
SENTINEL = 'XX'

def main():
    sales_force = []
    commission = []
    sales_force = create_sales_force()
    commission = create_commission(sales_force)


def create_sales_force():
    s_force = []
    last_name = input("Employee's Last Name (xx to quit): ")
    while last_name.upper() != SENTINEL:
        first_name = input("Employee's First Name: ")
        valid_sales_amount = False
        while not valid_sales_amount:
            try:
                sales_amount = float(input("Sales Amount: "))
            except ValueError:
                print("-- INVALID SALES AMOUNT --")
            else:
                if 0 <= sales_amount <= 50000:
                    valid_sales_amount = True
                else:
                    print("**INVALID SALES AMOUNT**")
                    print("Number must be between 0 and 50,000")

        sales_person_list = [last_name, first_name, sales_amount]
        s_force.append(sales_person_list)

        last_name = input("Employee's Last Name (xx to quit): ")

    return s_force

def create_commission(s_list):
    c_list = []
    for count in range(0, len(s_list)):
        s_comm = []
        s_comm[0] = count[0]
        s_comm[1] = count[1]
        s_comm[2] = find_commission(count[2])
        c_list.append(s_comm)

    return c_list



def find_commission(sales_amt):
    if sales_amt <= 5000:
        return sales_amt * .08
    elif 5000 < sales_amt <= 10000:
        return sales_amt * .11
    elif 10000 < sales_amt <= 18000:
        return sales_amt * .14
    elif 18000 < sales_amt <= 50000:
        return sales_amt * .18


main()
```

Comment: This is a very long way to ask your question. Can you ask again more concisely? i.e. remove unnecessary code and describe yourself what you think you should be doing.

Comment: Can't stress that more. The ability to figure out what exactly is the problem you are trying to solve, and to create a minimal test case, will not only help you get answers here - but in every place including from your own self.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `count` is an `int`, and you can't index an `int`.
What I think you're trying to do is to create, for each employee, an entry to a the list `c_list`.
What you can do, is to use `count` as an index for the list `s_list`, such as:

```
def create_commission(s_list):
    c_list = []
    for count in range(0, len(s_list)):
        s_comm = []
        s_comm.append(s_list[count][0])
        s_comm.append(s_list[count][1])
        s_comm.append(find_commission(s_list[count][2]))
        c_list.append(s_comm)

    return c_list
```

Note that `s_comm` is initially empty, so you have to `append` new component to that list, and you cannot directly index them (they do not exist before `append`ing new data)

Moreover, there is no need to use the the functions `range` and `len`, you can iterate directly on the element of the list with

```
def create_commission(s_list):
    c_list = []
    for e in s_list:
        s_comm = []
        s_comm.append(e[0])
        s_comm.append(e[1])
        s_comm.append(e[2])
        c_list.append(s_comm)

return c_list
```